# Fault Consumer not working with Masstransit JobConsumers and GenericFaultConsumer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, masstransit

I have this configuration. I am trying to get a generic fault consumer working for job consumers.
I am not sure if fault is being published or not.

```
    public class GenericFaultConsumer : IConsumer<Fault>
    {


        public  async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Fault> context)
        {
            Console.Write("max retry has been reached");
            //log errors
            //send email notification
        }
    }
```

from program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<BeanJobConsumer, BeanJobConsumerDefinition>();
    x.AddConsumer<CoffeeJobConsumer, CoffeeJobConsumerDefinition>();
    x.AddConsumer<OrderJobConsumer, OrderJobConsumerDefinition>();
    x.AddConsumer<TrackJobConsumer>();
    x.AddConsumer<GenericFaultConsumer>();
    x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
    x.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Immediate(5));

        cfg.UseDelayedMessageScheduler();

        cfg.ServiceInstance(instance =>
        {
            instance.ConfigureJobServiceEndpoints();
            instance.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
        });
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });

});
```

Consumer

```
 public class BeanJobConsumer : IJobConsumer<BeanDetail>
 {
     private readonly IBaristaService _baristaService;
     private readonly ILogger<BeanJobConsumer> _logger;
     public BeanJobConsumer(IBaristaService baristaService, ILogger<BeanJobConsumer> logger)
     {
         _baristaService = baristaService;
         _logger = logger;
     }
     public async Task Run(JobContext<BeanDetail> context)
     {
         _logger.LogInformation("BeanConsumer is Doing the Job...");
         throw new Exception("Bean Not Found");
     }
 }
```

I am expecting that fault consumer will be executed.

Comment: Logging in debug would show whether or not the fault was published. Older versions of MassTransit may not have produced the `Fault` or `Fault<T>`, might have only produced `JobFaulted`.

Comment: I just checked the logs, it seems like it produced JobFaulted, FaultJob, JobSlotReleased. I am using version 8.1.0

Comment: The unit tests confirm that `Fault<TJob>` should be produced.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson here is the repo. https://github.com/kranz912/CoffeeMakerMessageQueue

Comment: Found it. By removing  `cfg.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Immediate(5));`  it works.